# agl-sota u-boot raspberrypi3 - Card did not respond to voltage select! Device 0: unknown device

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, u-boot, automotive-grade-linux

I am building an automotive-grade-linux demo image using yocto for raspberrypi3.
I am adding a layer agl-sota for OTA feature. This is where my u-boot breaks.
While booting up according to defconfig CONFIG_ENV_EXT4_DEVICE_AND_PART="0:1" u-boot takes mmc0 which is sd card that can be verified through 'mmc info' and partition 1.
Yet it shows:

```
U-Boot 2020.10 (Jun 29 2020 - 03:06:40 +0000)

DRAM:  768 MiB
RPI 3 Model B (0xa02082)
MMC:   mmc@7e202000: 0, sdhci@7e300000: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   vidconsole
Err:   vidconsole
Net:   No ethernet found.
starting USB...
Bus usb@7e980000: USB DWC2
scanning bus usb@7e980000 for devices... 3 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
Card did not respond to voltage select!

Device 0: unknown device
Waiting for Ethernet connection... unable to connect.
...
...
u-boot >
```

'mmc info' output:

```
U-Boot> mmc info
Device: mmc@7e202000
Manufacturer ID: 3
OEM: 5344
Name: SU16G 
Bus Speed: 50000000
Mode: SD High Speed (50MHz)
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 3.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 14.8 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
```

What configuration issue is disallowing u-boot to boot the kernel.?
I am using raspberrypi imager for flashing the wic.xz image.

Comment: Which version of the Raspberry Pi 3 do you use? Is the problem reproducible with U-Boot v2021.04 and with the current upstream? Which configuration file do you use?  u-boot.bin is a file placed on the first boot partition. You don't need any special tool to copy the file.

Comment: Thanks, @Xypron for looking at this. 
Apparently, my issue is solved. This was an issue particular to the AGL Koi release packaging script when agl-sota yocto layer was used along. 

The .wic.xz image generated was missing boot.scr and uEnv.txt which causes u-boot to skip mmc boot and goes to network boot which is next in the boot order. Manually copying these two files from the build directory to the boot partition solved the issue. Copying boot.scr alone did not solve my issue previously and this speculated a u-boot configuration issue.
Both Pi4 and Pi3 boot perfectly now.